# Hashing python functions across different sessions

Tags: python, hash

I want to generate a hash based on the parameters of the function (for some quick automated caching). The hash should be consistent between different sessions.

Let's assume I have the following functions:

```
def generate_hash(dictionary):
  return hashlib.sha224(str(dictionary.items())).hexdigest()

def foo(a,b,c):
 return generate_hash(locals())
```

Which is perfectly fine as long as the arguments `str` representation is consistent across sessions. The problem is that often I pass function as arguments and looks like they are not.

For example, the following call will return a different result across sessions.

```
foo(1,2,np.sum)
```

Any workaround?

Comment: What do you mean by hashable? I don't know the details of Python's hash library, but you can hash any length and amount of any binary data.

Comment: Didn't explain myself well. Check out the example I just added.

Comment: what happens if you call the hash builtin function ? I know the documentation says it calculates the hash of an object, but that object could be a tuple of the parameters

Comment: Your code works fine for me, with one possible exception. Are you trying to cache the results across runs, or across interpreters? Within a single session, the hashes of functions as written should be consistent.

Comment: @Wilduck, I am trying to cache between different sessions.

Comment: So that's the actual question here. I would recommend editing your question to include that _very_ important information.

Comment: You're right. I updated the question

Comment: I added a couple more clarifications. Feel free to change them if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I figured something out myself:

```
 16 def generate_hash(dictionary):
 17   args = []
 18   for key,item in dictionary.iteritems():
 19     if isinstance(item,functools.partial):
 20       args.append((key,item.func.__module__,item.func.__name__,                                                  
 21         generate_hash(item.keywords)))
 22     elif inspect.isfunction(item):
 23       args.append((key,item.__module__,item.__name__))
 24     else:
 25       args.append((key,item))
 26   return hashlib.sha224(str(args)).hexdigest()
```

which also works consistenly with partial functions:

```
foo('a','1',np.average)                         -> 1631c5fd0050fd01cb7a7ee9666d366b35c1415cb4181c7220ead043
foo('a',1,functools.partial(np.average,axis=0)) -> 692227d3b52b0cdcd4ed2204650cb207c1ab6f274a09977c711d35d5                                                            
foo('a',1,functools.partial(np.average,axis=1)) -> ba1e0b01f2e12ef1c9ca2e3bf5235aaadcbe4ab29d9c977e1ee6e799
```

Comment: I was about to post something similar. However, I would add that you should also include the `.__module__` attribute in your hash. Which will make it much less likely that you'll see a collision (your example, `np.sum`, would collide with the builtin `sum`).

Comment: As a note, this is a fragile implementation, which I would not count on for long term storage. If you update numpy, for example, it could break your caching. However, if you need something that will work in the short term, this will probably be okay.